# How to get data from SQL Server to DevExpress FileManager without EntityDataSource

Tags: sql-server, devexpress, file-manager

I use DevExpress `FileManager`. I want to retrieve data from the database to the `FileManager`, and all operations to modify in database should be without using an `EntityDataSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an SQL data source instead:

ASPxFilemanager:

```
<dx:ASPxFileManager ID="ASPxFileManager1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    ...
</dx:ASPxFileManager>
```

SQLDatasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString=""
SelectCommand="" 
DeleteCommand=""
InsertCommand=""
UpdateCommand="">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

An example here: [ASPxFileManager](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4440)

Comment: Thank you dcreight